# Update binary file using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, file, objectoutputstream

Am writing three objects to a binary file using below code in java.

```
oout = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
oout.writeObject(objClass1);             
oout.writeObject(objClass2);              
oout.writeObject(objClass3);
```

Then how can i want to modify some data in the objClass1 and update the file? Also append objClass3 to the end of file.

Thanks....

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update just one object, you need to overwrite the whole file. Read all 3 objects from file then write them back with new objClass1 version

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write at the beginning of a file that has contents so you need to read the content , update what you want and write again all the content... this isn't very efficient so i propose 2 solutions :

- write each object to a separate file
- use a object store like [HashStore](http://www.cellspark.com/hashstore.html) , [Neodatis](http://neodatis.wikidot.com/), [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) etc
- you can use a rdms to store the objects ([BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) type in mysql) in a serialized way